# Why docker-entrypoint.sh is not being found within the directory?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a Flask app in Docker using docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'


services:

  users:
    build:
        context: ./services/users
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
        - 5001:5000
    environment:
        - FLASK_ENV=development
        - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
        - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev
        - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test
    depends_on:
        - users-db
        
users-db:
    build:
        context: ./services/users/project/db
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 5435:5432
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.6-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --virtual --no-cache gcc python3-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && apk add netcat-openbsd

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

error output:

> Cannot start service users: failed to create task for container:
> failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create
> failed: unable to start container process: exec:
> "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh": stat
> /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown

I've double checked if the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file is in correct location and it is.
Strangely enough the build works locally but when I deploy it on AWS EC2 service the build fails with the error output above. Both environments use the same operating system. Yet I get different behaviours.

The error does not make sense to me since locally the build finds the file just fine but in remote server it cannot be found.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: …because you are mounting a volume over the app folder.

Comment: In [this answer](/a/77230416) for example I explain why the `volumes:` can cause trouble.  The database container should have `volumes:` so it doesn't lose data on restart, but the application container should not.

Comment: @DavidMaze before I submit answer to this would you explain to me why this isn't an issue locally but it is an issue in production ?

Comment: If you have `volumes:` that overwrite the application's source, then what runs in the container is the source code you have on the host and not what's in the image.  That forces you to separately copy the source code, and leads back to the "but it works on my machine" problem that Docker can frequently help avoid.